# Como esconder e depois mostrar um article?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse article:

```
<article class="detalhes">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT `nomep`, `cidade`,`bairro`, `endereco`, `site`, `site`, `email`, `facebook`, `googleplus`, `descricao`, `funciona` FROM `cadastropn` WHERE `cidade` = '$cidade' && `id` = '1'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo'<div id="detalhes"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo">'.$linha['nomep'];
            echo'<br><br>'.$linha['bairro'].','.$linha['cidade'];
            echo'<br>'.$linha['endereco'];
        }
        ?>
    </article>
```

que quero que fique escondido inicialmente, pra que só quando eu clicar nessa div:
`<div id="lista"><img src="_imagens/pizzaiolo_corpo-300x288.png" class="logo"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></div>`
Aquele article apareça.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versão com Javascript puro

```js
document.getElementById("lista").onclick = fadeToggle;

function fadeToggle(evt) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("detalhes");
    el[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.detalhes {
    display: none;
}

.detalhes.show {
    display: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="lista">
  Div lista com Javascript puro
</div>

<article class="detalhes">
  Conteúdo do article vai aqui...
</article>
```

Versão com jQuery

```js
$('#lista').click(function () {
  $('.detalhes').fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<div id="lista">
  Div lista com jQuery
</div>

<article class="detalhes" style="display:none">
  Conteúdo do article vai aqui...
</article>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar o elemento escondido, logo que entra na tela, exemplo:

```
$(".detalhes").hide();
```

E quando clicar div lista, exibe ela:

```
$("#detalhes").show();
```

Você vai querer esconder os detalhes novamente, ou deixar aparecendo? Caso não queira deixar exibindo o tempo todo, você terá .toggle(); ao invés de .show();

```
$("#detalhes").toggle();
```

Entendeu?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira com Javascript puro:

```js
(function() {

  var detalhes = document.getElementsByClassName('detalhes');
  //Esconde o elemento article.
  detalhes[0].style.display = 'none';
  
  var lista = document.getElementById('lista');
  
  //Adiciona o evento de click na DIV para mostrar o elemento quando ela for clicada.
  lista.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    //Mostrar article.
   detalhes[0].style.display = 'block';
  
  }, false);
 
})();
```

```html
<div id="lista"><h2>Mostrar</h2></div>

<article class="detalhes">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ullam ad voluptates quisquam libero beatae voluptatum eligendi recusandae provident, unde alias esse corporis placeat in molestias quae eaque, a sed!
</article>
```

Ou então caso você esteja usando jQuery, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
$(function() {

  var detalhes = $('.detalhes');
  //Esconde o elemento article.
  detalhes.hide();
  
  //Adiciona o evento de click na DIV para mostrar o elemento quando ela for clicada.
  $('#lista').click(function() {
  
    //Mostrar article
   detalhes.show();
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista"><h2>Mostrar</h2></div>

<article class="detalhes">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ullam ad voluptates quisquam libero beatae voluptatum eligendi recusandae provident, unde alias esse corporis placeat in molestias quae eaque, a sed!
</article>
```